# How to escape delimiter while tokenizing string in java

Tags: java

I have a regex pattern like                      `"(\\d{4},\\d{2},\\d{2} :\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})"`
I am passing this pattern as argument to a function which tokenizes the input string based on `","`.

Example:

```
func((\\d{4},\\d{2},\\d{2} :\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}),func(n))";
```

How do I escape the comma in the regex while tokenizing?

Comment: pass the regex as a String. Use Double quotes on both the sides

Comment: Can you edit your question to elaborate your problem? It is unclear what you are asking for. Also include the full source code you have, what you are trying to do and why it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please post the function which tokenizes the string? Could help with respect to your code then.

With no such information, you could use split() as follows(if all you want to do is split on ","):

```
String s = "Messages,Hello\,World,Hobbies,Java\,Programming";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("(?<!\\\\),")));
```

Refer -  http://www.javacreed.com/how-to-split-a-string-with-escaped-delimiters/

You could replace your code with:

```
String str = "(\\d{4}\\,\\d{2}\\,\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}), func(a)";
String[] tokens = str.split("(?<!\\\\),");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
```

This will give you a string array of tokens split on ","

Comment: String str = "(\\d{4}\\,\\d{2}\\,\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}), func(a)";
StringTokenizer stra = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");

Comment: Why don't you use split to do the same?Split or regex is the recommended approach.
StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: Thank you @Derryl Thomas for the answer.As you suggested using split functionality instead of String Tokenizer resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The @Derryl Thomas answer is probably the correct answer.
Here is an alternate technique.

1. Use something else to indicate the comma in your regex.
2. Split based on commas.
3. Change the "something else" back to a comma.

For example:

1. Instead of `"(\\d{4},\\d{2},\\d{2} :\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})"`
   Use `"(\\d{4}boppity\\d{2}boppity\\d{2} :\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})"`
2. Do the split based on comma.
3. Change the "boppity" in the regex to a ","; perhaps like this:
   `newStringVariable = yourStringVariable.replace("boppity", ",")`